# Split the list into lines

Tags: python

I have a full_list as follows:

```
full_list = [[[-180, 90], [-180, 80], [-175, 80], [-175, 90]], [[-180, 80], [-180, 70], [-175, 70], [-175, 80]], [[-180, 70], [-180, 60], [-175, 60], [-175, 70]], [[-180, 60], [-180, 50], [-175, 50], [-175, 60]]]
```

How can I produce the list called ans as follows?

```
ans = [[[-180, 90], [-180, 80], [-175, 80], [-175, 90]],
       [[-180, 80], [-180, 70], [-175, 70], [-175, 80]],
       [[-180, 70], [-180, 60], [-175, 60], [-175, 70]],
       [[-180, 60], [-180, 50], [-175, 50], [-175, 60]]]
```

Both list are same, only difference is the later one is splitted into lines.

Comment: What?  Are you printing the list somewhere, that you'd want portions of the list to appear on different lines?

Comment: Those look completely identical

Comment: Is this for printing purpose? then: `pprint.pprint(full_list)` is what you need.

Comment: This is for PRINTING purpose only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you talking about pretty printing? Your list is already like that.

```
>>> full_list = [[[-180, 90], [-180, 80], [-175, 80], [-175, 90]], [[-180, 80], [-180, 70], [-175, 70], [-175, 80]], [[-180, 70], [-180, 60], [-175, 60], [-175, 70]], [[-180, 60], [-180, 50], [-175, 50], [-175, 60]]]

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(full_list)
[[[-180, 90], [-180, 80], [-175, 80], [-175, 90]],
 [[-180, 80], [-180, 70], [-175, 70], [-175, 80]],
 [[-180, 70], [-180, 60], [-175, 60], [-175, 70]],
 [[-180, 60], [-180, 50], [-175, 50], [-175, 60]]]
```

Comment: yes, it was what I was looking for. Will be accepted. By the way how if I have to put two sublists into one line, i.e., [[-180, 90], [-180, 80], [-175, 80], [-175, 90]], [[-180, 80], [-180, 70], [-175, 70], [-175, 80]]

Comment: `pprint` can't do that by itself, you'd need to code that part yourself

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer, `pprint` is the natural way to go.

But depending on your precise needs, you might do this as well:

```
print(*full_list, sep='\n')

# Output:
[[-180, 90], [-180, 80], [-175, 80], [-175, 90]]
[[-180, 80], [-180, 70], [-175, 70], [-175, 80]]
[[-180, 70], [-180, 60], [-175, 60], [-175, 70]]
[[-180, 60], [-180, 50], [-175, 50], [-175, 60]]
```

To customise a bit, you can use `range`:

```
def my_custom_printer(full_list):
    for i in range(0, len(full_list), 2):
        try:
            print("{}, {}".format(full_list[i], full_list[i+1]))
        except IndexError:
            # len(full_list) is odd, so just print the last index
            print(full_list[i])

my_custom_printer(full_list)

# Output:
[[-180, 90], [-180, 80], [-175, 80], [-175, 90]], [[-180, 80], [-180, 70], [-175, 70], [-175, 80]]
[[-180, 70], [-180, 60], [-175, 60], [-175, 70]], [[-180, 60], [-180, 50], [-175, 50], [-175, 60]]
```

But then it gets a bit dirty... Mainly because the actual data and its representation are not strictly consistent anymore

Comment: Or `print(*full_list, sep='\n')` if `print()` function is available.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary correct, didn't think about that. Answer updated (if you don't mind)